# WPF. ListView внутри ListView не байндится

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

Код для примера.В рабочем коде все интерфейсы, в частности `INotifyPropertyChanged` реализованы как надо, здесь я многие моменты опускаю.Думаю что суть вопроса будет ясна

Есть коллекция объектов

```
public ObservableCollection<ObjKind_1> ObjKind_1Collection { get; set; }
```

Сам класс `ObjKind_1` представляет из себя:

```
public class ObjKind_1
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObjKind_2> ObjKind_2Collection { get; set; }
    public ObjKind_1()
    {
        ObjKind_2Collection = new ObservableCollection<ObjKind_2>();
    }
}
```

В свою очередь `ObjKind_2` есть:

```
public class ObjKind_2
{
    string _dbname;

    public ObjKind_2()
    {           
    }
    public string DBname
    {
        get => _dbname;
        set => Set(ref _dbname, value);//реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
    }    
}
```

Собственно код XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource = "{Binding ObjKind_1Collection}" >
   < ListView.ItemTemplate >
      < DataTemplate >
         < StackPanel >
            < ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjKind_2Collection}">
               <TextBlock Text = "{Binding DBname}" />
            </ ListView >
         </ StackPanel >
      </ DataTemplate >
   </ ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ ListView >
```

И такой код не работает. Ругается в момент добавления элементов в коллекцию `ObjKind_2Collection` и ссылается на строку `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding DBname}" />`. В отладчике получаю:

```
InvalidOperationException: Операция недопустима, когда ItemsSource используется. Вместо этого получите доступ и измените элементы с помощью ItemsControl.ItemsSource.
```

Что-то нашел на англ. стеке, но что-то я не понимаю как это использовать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w

Где я не то делаю? Извиняюсь, если жестко туплю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта часть:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjKind_2Collection}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding DBname}" />
        </ListView>
```

неправильна. Вам нужно указать снова `ItemTemplate`:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjKind_2Collection}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding DBname}" />
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

А вы вместо этого указываете контент внутреннего списка.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте `ItemTemplate` для элемента `ListView`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjKind_2Collection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding DBname}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView >
```